# Recipe Questions

Tags: discussion, off-topic, recipe

In the definition stage the recipe questions were noted as off-topic.

I'd like to confirm that they are still considered off topic by the community.

See [Can somebody give me a good recipe that they've tried for a sour beer?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/269/can-somebody-give-me-a-good-recipe-that-theyve-tried-for-a-sour-beer)

Gordon and I have voted to close as off-topic, I'd just like a bit more clarity from the rest of the community.

**EDIT**
Here is the [link to the definition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1619?phase=definition), unfortunately I can't link directly to the recipe question, but it's titled "What's a good recipe for a traditional IPA?", there is also one about cloning Sierra Nevada

Comment: Can you post a link to the definition?  I think recipes could be a good think so long as they don't get duped over and over again.

Answer (score 8):

How about we make [this question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/366/what-are-some-good-online-sources-for-recipes) into a community wiki? Then we have something to point people at when we close recipe questions.

Comment: I like that idea. Anyone else?

Comment: Yeah, good idea.

Comment: +1 seems good to me, it's sure to be a recurring question and as a result should go in the FAQ as well.

Comment: We may want an additional CW (or perhaps even one per style) that has "recommended recipes" where you can post recipes you've tried and liked.

Comment: What's a CW?  BTW, thats what I was expecting when I posted a recipe request for the sour, that any further requests for the same type would be marked dupe and closed.

Comment: CW is Community Wiki. I would support reopening your question and making it a CW, perhaps with a rewording to make it more specific to a style, but I'm not sure anyone has enough rep yet to make CWs... sgwill, do you have that ability yet? We definitely need to get this worked out before the public beta starts and get it on the FAQ.

Comment: Just discovered most of us have the ability to make community wikis. I think we just need to work out what the FAQ should say, something along the lines of all recipe posts are CW, and only one recipe CW per style.

Answer (score 2):

That's fine by me. Let's keep the site to techniques, etc. The question in question (ha) would be acceptable, then, if he asked about how to make a sour beer, right?

Comment: correct, if he said. "I really like Lambic, what steps are different from normal brewing?" for sure, upvote from me.