# What should be on our FAQ?

Tags: discussion

Another [Essential Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

Answer (score 4):

Here's my proposal:

> Homebrew SE is for **dedicated home brewers and serious enthusiasts**. If you have a question about …
>
> - the brewing process
> - brew appreciation
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - selling alcohol
> - buying commercially brewed products
> - irresponsible consumption of alcohol
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

And why:

- The brewing process covers ingredients, equipment, flavours produced by the process and all of the obvious technical questions
- Brew appreciation covers competitive brewing/judging, food pairings, glassware, discussion of commercially brewed products, recommendations & the edge cases we have embraced so far

I think appreciation is an important aspect we should cover explicitly.  In my opinion it's the brewer's *raison d'être* - it's certainly mine!

Answer (score 0):

When we get the [Recipe Questions issue](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/recipe-questions) all sorted out, we should spell out our policy in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

I could have an opinion, but the community wiki that has been mentioned is something that I am unaware of. It isn't really obvious how to go from the main Homebrewing home page to this wiki. If this were made more obvious, that certainly would be an alternative.

Comment: There isn't a specific "community wiki" (other than the entire site as a collection), a CW is a type of question/answer.  Find out more here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts